# How to communicate between docker containers?

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose

I have two containers: a NextJS13 frontend and a .NET API backend linked using docker compose.

I am calling using my frontend `fetch('http://backend:8080/api/User')`. However, it throws the following error:

```
info Generating static pages (0/4)TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11413:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 8080
  }
}

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11413:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I am also using github actions and the frontend doesn't build properly in an isolated environment.

My question is, how do I resolve this issue, or is there another easier way for the containers to interact with each other? I'm also considering just spinning up two different apps with one container in each.

Comment: On a container context `localhost` means the container itself. You cant connect the backend with `localhost`, instead you have to provide the container name or ip.

Comment: In your docker-compose file you have name for the service, That's what you should be using instant of localhost. so if your service named `backend` you should be using `fetch('http://backend:8080/api/User')` instant of localhost.

Comment: If I change the localhost to my service name 'backend', nextjs still shows the error on build

Comment: could you add docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Is the NextJS application actually running in the end user's browser (even if the code is being served from a container; do you see the error messages in a browser console)?  If so, it's not in a container and you can't use Docker networking features.  You need to connect to the published `ports:` of the backend using the server's DNS name (nothing container-specific), or use a relative-path URL via a reverse proxy.